# Hide Android App from launcher list on Android TV

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-tv

I want to hide my Android app from the Android TV launcher list.

Is there any way to hide an Android app from the Android TV launcher list? I removed the activity class from the code and removed the manifest activity declaration as well. But the Android app is still showing up in the launcher list.

Note:
I want to use the application class.

Comment: If you want to uninstall the app, you can try `adb uninstall <package-name>`. This should remove it from the launcher's list as well.

Comment: @vighnesh153 am not asking about uninstalling the app.

Comment: In the end, what shows up in any launcher (on a phone, TV, etc.) is up to the developers of that launcher.

Comment: @CommonsWare Mobile and tablet launchers are not showing my app. But TV launchers are showing the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is like hidden system apps try delete intent filter

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Kindly note. I removed totally from manifest and class file.